# Reload Same URL in Webview An When Refresh Page

Tags: java, android, webview, reload, swiperefreshlayout

I created a little android app to view a responsive website. I have implemented a pull refresh and it works, however when pulling on refresh it redirect to the home page I put in the LoadUrl. How to refresh by reloading the same url the user is visiting ?

My java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                LoadWeb();
            }
        });

        LoadWeb();
    }

    public void LoadWeb()
    {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        //tiga baris dibawah ini agar laman yang dimuat dapat
        //melakukan zoom
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        //baris dibawah ini untuk menambahkan scrollbar didalam webview-nya
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //ketika loading selesai, ikon loading akan hilang
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                if (webView.getProgress()==100){
                    swipe.setRefreshing(false);
                }else {
                    swipe.setRefreshing(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In Swipe Refresh layout call webView.reload();

```
swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            webView.reload();
        }
    });
```